# Retain \n in jsp page

Tags: html, spring, jsp, textarea, jstl

I have the following code:

```
<form:textarea rows="3" cols="21"  path="marksAndNumbers" onchange="changed()" htmlEscape="false"/></td>
```

When I debug the value of "marksAndNumbers" in my controller.it is displayed as follows:

```
Stores
PO# 4640995
DPCI-Item# 069000364
Style# TB1124
COLOR 
SIZE 
CASEPACK 6
COUNTRY OF ORIGIN 
CHINA
```

But when I try to display this using `<textarea>` tag,the newline is not retained and everything is displayed in the same line.

```
StoresPO# 4640995 DPCI-Item# 069000364 Style# TB1124COLOR SIZE CASEPACK 6 COUNTRY OF ORIGIN CHINA
```

I tried to replace the "\n" with `"<br/>"` in my controller,this displayed as:

```
Stores
<br/>PO# 4640995
<br/>DPCI-Item# 069000364
<br/>Style# TB1124
<br/>COLOR 
<br/>SIZE 
<br/>CASEPACK 6
<br/>COUNTRY OF ORIGIN 
<br/>HEIGHT 19.81 CM
```

But if I display the same value using `c:out` it is displaying correctly.

Comment: Something is escaping your html.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most HTML elements, `<textarea>` preserves whitespace ([see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXMH2/1/)).

This means the solution is to render HTML with the newlines intact.

If it doesn't work for you, something must strip the whitespace on the way. To debug this:

1. Check the HTML in your web browser (source view). Are the newlines there?
2. Check the response in your web browser's JavaScript debugger. Are the newlines there?
3. Do you have filters installed in your web.xml that strip "unnecessary" whitespace?
4. Check the output of your JSP. Does it really write newlines to the output?